# Using Mac Excel 2011: Can't find the Delete Duplicates for removing duplicate rows

Tags: mac, microsoft-excel

I see lots of advice about Delete Duplicates but can't find the command at all. Looked under Tools and Data with no luck. Anyone else in the same boat - or if you know please let me know.

Thanks
Anita

Comment: Try to follow what's stated [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/mac-excel-help/filter-for-or-remove-duplicate-values-HA102927681.aspx). If the information in that page doesn't help you, please provide as much detail as possible, maybe include a screenshot if helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I've taken a quick screenshot for this. I've selected my data (1)... You won't find 'remove duplicates' in the Data menu (from the menu bar). Instead, click Data from the ribbon (2); click Remove Duplicates (3); confirm (4).

If you don't see the 'Data' option on the ribbon, then look on the far right of the green ribbon for the cog symbol. Click that, then 'Ribbon Preferences'. Then you'll get to a customisation page where you can toggle the visibility of different ribbon groups. Hope this solves it.

[image]